# Error during make gcc: "cp: Permission denied"

Tags: linux, gcc, build, permission-denied, cp

## What I did

In my initially empty build directory, I configure gcc with

`/home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc --enable-multilib --disable-shared --enable-static --disable-bootstrap --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-languages=all --enable-libgomp --enable-threads=posix --enable-tls --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-host-shared CFLAGS='-lpthread -fPIC' CXXFLAGS='-lpthread -fPIC' CPPFLAGS='-fPIC'`

I then issue `make` and after some successful building, the build ultimately fails with the following

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/anthony/Documents/gcc/gcc'
mkdir -p ada/bldtools/sinfo
rm -f ada/bldtools/sinfo/sinfo.ads ada/bldtools/sinfo/sinfo.adb ada/bldtools/sinfo/xsinfo.adb ada/bldtools/sinfo/csinfo.adb
cp -p /home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/sinfo.ads /home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/sinfo.adb /home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/xsinfo.adb /home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/csinfo.adb ada/bldtools/sinfo
make[2]: cp: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [/home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/Make-generated.in:44: ada/sinfo.h] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anthony/Documents/gcc/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4411: all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anthony/Documents/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:970: all] Error 2
```

## What I tried

I've tried

1. `sudo make`
2. `sudo chmod 777 -R` the gcc source and build directories
3. ````
   sudo cp -p /home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/sinfo.ads /home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/sinfo.adb /home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/xsinfo.adb /home/anthony/Documents/gcc-pi/gcc/gcc/ada/csinfo.adb ada/bldtools/sinfod ```
   ````

all of which failed at advancing the build. Note that the last command succeeds, but when I try to continue the build after that, it yields the same error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `all of which failed. Note that the last command succeeds` So it fails or succeeds? `make[2]: cp: Permission denied` Would that mean that your `make` doesn't have permission to execute `cp` program?

Comment: The cp from within the directory make was in succeeds, but that does not affect the build, namely it still gives the same error. I think the script does a rm -f on the directory before the cp which is why I can't have a workaround from executing the command myself.

Comment: @anthony_m what shell were you using ?

Comment: Also shouldn't this be considered a bug in make ?

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue. Looks like the problem relates to gcc package due to the fact that it contains "cp" directory. Solution was found in "https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libgccjit/?O=10&PP=10". In my case i had "." folder in my PATH environment variable. Removing it made compilation process to continue.

Comment: By renaming the folder named `cp`, I got the build progressing again, but making it work, you'd need to rename the `cp` folders and the built files insides, it's a very nasty error.

Answer (score 0):

Edit ./gcc/Makefile
replace cp with /usr/bin/cp

Comment: This is a correct indication. The command cp is not recognized and one has to specify it by a full path.